# How to originate two dial plans from fs_cli

Tags: freeswitch

I have tried command
originate user/1001 &bridge(sofia/internal/1234@192.168.0.130)
Its working but my requirement is to hit two dialplans and make them communicate
I tried originate sofia/internal/1235@192.168.0.130 &bridge(sofia/internal/1234@192.168.0.130)
It is throwing errors like [ERR] sofia.c:7360 Cannot Blind Transfer 1 Legged calls

Please suggest me some solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to originate two applications from fs\_cli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894743/how-to-originate-two-applications-from-fs-cli)