# how to originate two applications from fs_cli

Tags: freeswitch

Please answer this interesting question, I want to make two applications communicate with each other in free switch without a sip user, I have tried following things on fs_cli

originate user/1001 &bridge(Sofia/internal/1789)
user is able to communicate with the application

originate Sofia/internal/1235 &bridge(Sofia/internal/1789)
but this is throwing error that "cannot blind transfer 1235";
I noticed that by default a sip call is originated with caller id:<00000000> and transferring call to sip user in first case but unable to transfer to dial plan in second case please help me

Answer (score 0):

Loopback is for you, create an extension / dialplan with one application and reload the dialplan, and then at fs_cli you can use loopback in originate to dial that application and at the other end enter second application, that's all

https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Loopback_endpoint

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working. I just need some other help from u, I executed this command from fs_cli its working but actual requirement is to make it work from java application. If u can give me some suggestions I will be achieving it.

Comment: if you ever originated a call from java, then there is nothing new just use loopback syntax as dialstring instead of "sofia"

Comment: Actually the issue is java application originates a call only when it is invoked. My requirement is that when I run a java application in eclipse it should originate two applications